# No audio while playing video in PotPlayer

Tags: daum-pot-player

PotPlayer used to play everything correctly, making me switch away from VLC.

Today it appears to not play any audio, though. Mute is off, volume up, same for system, audio stream both, and audio renderer automatic. What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PotPlayer menu, Audio, Output Mode was "Pass-through after AC3 re-encoding" instead of "PCM (Default) (Recommended)".

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, my fix was:

Audio > Audio Effects > Voice Removal

It was enabled by unknowingly using a shortcut: [Shift]+[V]

Answer (score 1):

My fix was Audio>Audio Renderer>Waveout (instead of Directsound or Autoselect)

Answer (score 0):

Installing again was the last and successfull option for me.
Audio was completly stuck using this media player.